# Can't "Safely Remove Hardware And Eject Media" using remote desktop as a regular user

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, taskbar, safely-remove-hardware

I have a remote computer (Windows 7 Pro) that I sometimes need to connect to in order to safely remove and eject a DOK. When using that remoter computer locally (physically, not through remote desktop), that little taskbar button of safely removing appears both when logged in through an admin account and through a regular account. However, when connecting to that same PC remotely through remote desktop, only when logging in as the admin, one can safely remove. When logging in through a regular account (Which I rather do, for various reasons), that taskbar button simply does not appear. I am guessing that this is an intended limitation of Remote Desktop, but I couldn't find a way (And I did my fair share of google searches) to change this behavior.

I'll appreciate any idea and thought. Thanks!